# How to consolidate the output of a number of Lambda function calls

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a large file which I want to process using Lambda functions in AWS. Since I can not control the size of the file, I came up with the solution to distribute the processing of the file to multiple lambda function calls to avoid timeouts. Here's how it works:

1. I dedicated a bucket to accept the new input files to be processed.
2. I set a trigger on the bucket to handle each time a new file is uploaded (let's call it `uploadHandler`)
3. Reading the file, `uploadHandler` measures the size of the file and splits it into equal chunks.
4. Each chunk is sent to `processor` lambda function to be processed.

Notes:

- The `uploadHandler` does **not** read the file content.
- The data sent to `processor` is just a `{ start: #, end: # }`.
- Multiple instances of the `processor` are called in parallel.
- Each `processor` call reads its own chunk of the file individually and generates the output for it.

So far so good. The problem is how to consolidate the output of the all `processor` calls into one output? Does anyone have any suggestion? And also how to know when the execution of all the `processor`s is done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently had a similar problem. I solve it using AWS lambda and Step functions using this solution https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-create-iterate-pattern-section.html

In this specific example the execution doesn't happen in Parallel, but it's sequential. But when the state machine finish to execute you have the garantee that the file was totally processed correctly. I don't know if is exactly what you are looking.

Comment: Don't forget to consider financial implications. Step functions usually ends up being more expensive than Lambda itself (which is kind of strange to pay more for managing a process than performing the process itself). If you have a complex workflow and maybe it changes too frequently, Step Functions might pay for itself. In other cases, you may be better off coding your own logic directly in Lambda, as the options I outlined below exemplify.

Comment: True, but depends on the size. The free tier supports 4000 invocations for free. In our case we have less than 500 invocations for a month, so it's perfect for us.

Answer (score 2):

## Option 1:

1. After breaking the file, make the `uploadHandler` function call the `processor` functions synchronously.
2. Make the calls concurrent, so that you can trigger all `processors` at once. Lambda functions have only one vCPU (or 2 vCPUs if RAM > 1,800 Gb), but the requests are IO-bound, so you only need one processor.
3. The `uploadHandler` will wait for all `processors` to respond, then you can assemble all responses.

**Pros**: simpler to implement, no storage;

**Cons**: no visibility on what's going on until everything is finished;

## Option 2:

1. Persist a `processingJob` in a DB (RDS, DynamoDB, whatever). The `uploadHandler` would create the job and save the number of parts into which the file was broken up. Save the job ID with each file part.
2. Each `processor` gets one part (with the job ID), processes it, then store in the DB the results of the processing.
3. Make each `processor` check if it's the last one delivering its results; if yes, make it trigger an `assembler` function to collect all results and do whatever you need.

**Pros**: more visibility, as you can query your storage DB at any time to check which parts were processed and which are pending; you could store all sorts of metadata from the `processor` for detailed analysis, if needed;

**Cons**: requires a storage service and a slightly more complex handling of your Lambdas;